# How to implement the thread in multiple tab in single event?

Tags: mfc

I have working on Dialog based application,In Main Dialog multiple tab are there, every tab has single event and in every event has multiple operation like that,(two or three button are pressed simultaneously if ,suppose that x button is press and process and press the y button do not interrelate with other,execute our own process)so, how can I implement multi-threading ?
Accordingly the tab event, thread is process but without effecting any other thread statement or any other event.

I was try to implement the thread in main dialog to initialize the thread on OnInitDialog but its not working.

Comment: Without code you tried and language tag this post is unlikely to get answer. In current state post is looking for tutorial as an answer which is off-topic on SO.